# Como utilizar o "strcpy" e o " strcat" do C++?

Tags: c++

Como utilizar o `strcpy` e o `strcat` para pegar os nomes dos arquivos txt num diretório dentro da aplicação numa pasta chamada valor.

Comment: Você pode mostrar algo que você já tenha? Sua pergunta me parece muito ampla, existem várias formas de ler arquivos de texto, por exemplo. Que compilador está usado? Usas alguma IDE?

Comment: tenho alguns arquivos `txt` e gostaria de pegar esse nome pelo meto citado na pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

As funções (strcpy e strcat) e a listagem dos arquivos de um diretório são assuntos muito distintos, strcpy e strcat são apenas funções para copiar e contatenar strings e são usadas nesse caso apenas para gerar o diretorio onde sera listado os arquivos e não para listar os arquivos de um diretório.

Tanto o gerenciamento de strings quanto a listagem de um diretório pode ser feita de diversas maneiras, na maioria dos casos é usado o "dirent.h" para realizar a listagem de um diretório, mas eu constumo utilizar o proprio win32 API para realizar esta tarefa.

Esta é a maneira que eu acho mais fácil ao usar o Win32 API:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<wstring> GetFilesFromDirectory(wstring strDir)
{
   vector<wstring> AllFiles;
   WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
   HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
   //
   strDir += L"\\*";
   //
   hFind = FindFirstFile(strDir.c_str(), &ffd);
   //
   do
   {
      if (!(ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
      {
         AllFiles.push_back(wstring(ffd.cFileName));
      }
   }
   while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
   //
   FindClose(hFind);
   return AllFiles;
}

int main()
{
    // Lista os arquivos da pasta "C:\A"
    vector<wstring> files = GetFilesFromDirectory(L"C:\\A");

    for (int C = 0; C < files.size(); C++)
    {
        // Mostra na tela
        _tprintf(L" %s\n", files[C].c_str());
    }

    system("PAUSE");

}
```

Como mostra o exemplo acima, em nenhum momento foi utilizado o strcpy ou o strcat pois foi utilizado o iterator wstring que facilitou o trabalho de concatenar a string.

Para utilizar char ao invéz de wstring é só fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<string> GetFilesFromDirectory(wstring strDir)
{
   vector<string> AllFiles;
   WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
   HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
   //
   strDir += L"\\*";
   //
   hFind = FindFirstFile(strDir.c_str(), &ffd);
   //
   do
   {
      if (!(ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
      {
         wstring wideStr(ffd.cFileName);
         AllFiles.push_back(string(wideStr.begin(), wideStr.end()));
      }
   }
   while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
   //
   FindClose(hFind);
   return AllFiles;
}

int main()
{
    // Lista os arquivos da pasta "C:\A"
    vector<string> files = GetFilesFromDirectory(L"C:\\A");

    for (int C = 0; C < files.size(); C++)
    {
        // Mostra na tela
        printf(" %s\n", files[C].c_str());
    }

    system("PAUSE");

}
```

Este é o resultado da execução e a pasta listada:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado